# Which to use? new InputStreamReader with Socket.getInputStream or System.in

Tags: java

Do anyone know what is the difference between these two lines of codes?

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
String inputLine = in.readLine();

BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String inputLine = d.readLine();
```

They seem to serve the same purpose which is to receive user keyboard input.

Comment: They don't serve the same purpose, depending on what `clientSocket` is. I don't believe a client socket connection is used to read user keyboard input on the host where this java code is running.

Comment: @Progman, my teacher used these 2 lines in 2 codes examples. I have no idea why he want to use a client socket to read user input in the client class since System.in can do the same.

Comment: Maybe it's not the client class but the server class, where the input from the client is read.

Comment: @Progman, oh u r right, it is in Server class. but can System.in do the same in Server class? or need to use clientSocket.getInputStream() for server input?

Comment: You can use `System.in` in the Server class, but then you will read the keyboard input on the host where the server is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.in` reads data from the "standard" input stream:

> This stream is already open and ready to supply input data. Typically
>   this stream corresponds to keyboard input or another input source
>   specified by the host environment or user.

`clientSocket.getInputStream` reads data from the specific "client socket" you created.

Comment: but this clientSocket.getInputStream is being used in the client class file. So i don't understand why it want to read data from the same socket as System.in can do the same.